# Error configuring the requestmap in spring security core for grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

In my system, I have numerous roles assigned to the users (lets assume 3 for now `ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER, ROLE_SERVICES`). In one of my controllers (lets assume `SearchController` that we have three actions `serviceIndex{}, userIndex{} and adminIndex{}`), I want users of any role to be able to access two of the actions (the first two). For the final action, I want to restrict the action against a user of single role type (lets say ROLE_USER) but allow access to users of other roles (i.e. to `ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SERVICE`. I have something like the following in my requestmap table.

config_attribute ----------------------------------------------------------->url
   ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SERVICE,ROLE_USER ------------------------------> /search/serviceIndex
   ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SERVICE,ROLE_USER-------------------------------> /search/userIndex
   ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SERVICE -----------------------------------------> /search/adminIndex

Since the third rule states that the url '/search/adminIndex' is not accessible to ROLE_USER, the user with that role should have been denied the authorization to access the url. But, the user can still access the url. What is the correct configuration. I did try someting like `/search/adminIndex/**`, but that doesn't work either. On a side note, none of the urls will have suffixes furthermore but I would still like to prevent access if users manipulate the url like adding suffixes like `/search/userIndex/56a` just in case.

Regards,
dipess

Answer (score 1):

Since the plugin iterates through the rules and applies the first one that matches the current URL, I would set the adminIndex first and then have a catchall for anything else.

```
ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SERVICE            /search/adminIndex
ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SERVICE,ROLE_USER  /search/**
```

Comment: Even though you may be right, this logic seems flawed because each URL is different.  I really don't see why the OPs current config shouldn't work.

Comment: One reason could be that other rules that are not shown are matched before any of the ones pasted.  In that case my answer would be wrong as well.